# Setting cache Expires header to S3 files with Cyberduck

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, cyberduck

I would like to add Expires header to my images files stored in S3. I have just found out Cyberduck that easily add metadata. However, I would like to add Expires like 1 month after the request (like I do with static files in my webserver with Nginx). I don´t know if this is possible. Otherwise, I can set expires with a date, i.e 1 2018-06-20 but, I think when I get this date, I will need to update all my files with a new date in the future. I would like to set this header "dinamically" one month later. Is it possible? Any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000`.

This will tell the client that the object can be cached for up to 30 days from the time of download.

Setting `Expires` is no longer considered best practice, and in any event, S3 only supports a static value, here.